# can one application show a uialertview while another application is running?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, telephony

I have an app that tracks the incoming phone calls and another one that answers a phone call. I would like my app (from whatever reason) to show an alertview with the ongoing call the CallID. Is it possible with the phone app in particular?

Comment: If at all, then only on jailbroken devices.

Answer (score 0):

Well to answer your question, it is possible for one application to show an alert while another application is running. I don't think apple would allow that though if you're trying to submit to the appstore. But I have shown an alert view from SpringBoard while running other applications (using cycript), and SpringBoard itself is an application, so it is possible.

Comment: So I CAN show an alertview while the phone application is running and I am on a call?

Comment: I haven't thoroughly tested it, but I know that from running an application on my iPad, I can show an alertview from the SpringBoard app.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use local or push notification instead. It's like you are in an app while a SMS arrives. You will see a banner appearing on the top of the screen displaying a message, and you can tap on that to go to Messages app. See Apple Documentation for detail http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1